# Schengen visa - travel - without NIE

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, spain

I am in Spain with Type D visa expiring on Aug 2017. I had NIE but lost it. Can I travel to other Schengan countries without NIE?

Comment: What is a "NIE"?

Comment: @AliAwan: However, short trips to countries _where one does not live_ are on topic here, even if one is an expat where one does live.

Answer (score 1):

A type D visa allows you to travel freely *for up to 90 of every 180 days* in the Schengen countries other than the one that issued the visa.

"NIE" appears to be a Spanish personal identification number. It is unclear what you mean by having "lost" it. Did you simply forget which number you were assigned, or did the Spanish authorities actively cancel a number they had assigned you? In any case, this should not concern you for travel in the other Schengen states; the D visa is sufficient documentation for your right to do that.

Comment: Another possibility: *NIE* refers here to the ID card or other card that serves as proof that a certain NIE has been assigned to Brijesh.